# R data.table combine 2 data.tables of different lengths by adding replicated rows of the shorter data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here's code to create two data tables of different lengths. d1 has data every hour. d2 has data every 15 minutes. How do I replicate d1 data and combine it with d2 so d2 has 2 new columns - var1_hr and var2_hr that repeat 4 times (ie for each hour).

```
d1 <- data.table(ts_hr = as.POSIXct(c("2023-06-01 00:00:00", "2023-06-01 01:00:00")), var1_hr = as.numeric(c(3,4)), var2_hr = as.numeric(c(5,6)))
d2 <- data.table(ts_15 = as.POSIXct(c("2023-06-01 00:00:00", "2023-06-01 00:15:00", "2023-06-01 00:30:00", "2023-06-01 00:45:00",
                                      "2023-06-01 01:00:00", "2023-06-01 01:15:00", "2023-06-01 01:30:00", "2023-06-01 01:45:00")), 
                 var_15 = as.numeric(c(3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

d1 <- data.table(ts_hr = as.POSIXct(c("2023-06-01 00:00:00", "2023-06-01 01:00:00")), var1_hr = as.numeric(c(3,4)), var2_hr = as.numeric(c(5,6)))
d2 <- data.table(ts_15 = as.POSIXct(c("2023-06-01 00:00:00", "2023-06-01 00:15:00", "2023-06-01 00:30:00", "2023-06-01 00:45:00",
                                      "2023-06-01 01:00:00", "2023-06-01 01:15:00", "2023-06-01 01:30:00", "2023-06-01 01:45:00")),
                 var_15 = as.numeric(c(3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3)))

d1[d2,on=.(ts_hr=ts_15)] %>% na.locf
```

Produces this:

```
> d1[d2,on=.(ts_hr=ts_15)] %>% na.locf
                 ts_hr var1_hr var2_hr var_15
1: 2023-06-01 00:00:00       3       5    3.0
2: 2023-06-01 00:15:00       3       5    3.1
3: 2023-06-01 00:30:00       3       5    3.2
4: 2023-06-01 00:45:00       3       5    3.3
5: 2023-06-01 01:00:00       4       6    4.0
6: 2023-06-01 01:15:00       4       6    4.1
7: 2023-06-01 01:30:00       4       6    4.2
8: 2023-06-01 01:45:00       4       6    4.3
```

A few key points to note:

- Make sure you understand the join/merge syntax `d1[d2,...]` explained [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html). (Consider using `merge(...)` instead for clarity)
- [na.locf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-12/topics/na.locf) from zoo does the NA handling.

Comment: Works great. Need to add library(magrittr). Or leave out magrittr and use the native pipe as follows |> na.locf()

Comment: Ah yes, or just wrap that entire last statement in `na.locf(...)`

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `data.table::merge` and `data.table::nafill`

```
library(data.table)

Cols <- c("var1_hr", "var2_hr")

merge(d1, d2, by.x="ts_hr", by.y="ts_15", all=T)[
  , (Cols) := lapply(mget(Cols), \(x) nafill(x, "locf"))][]
                 ts_hr var1_hr var2_hr var_15
1: 2023-06-01 00:00:00       3       5    3.0
2: 2023-06-01 00:15:00       3       5    3.1
3: 2023-06-01 00:30:00       3       5    3.2
4: 2023-06-01 00:45:00       3       5    3.3
5: 2023-06-01 01:00:00       4       6    4.0
6: 2023-06-01 01:15:00       4       6    4.1
7: 2023-06-01 01:30:00       4       6    4.2
8: 2023-06-01 01:45:00       4       6    4.3
```